# Pure functions vs normal functions

Tags: pure-function

I am trying to understand the true difference/usage of a pure function vs a "normal" function. Besides the argument that a pure function is particularly handy when it comes to a single usage, are there any deeper reasons on why one should go for them rather than the "normal" ones?

Comment: I think the pros discussed on this page generally apply to the Wolfram Language as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

Comment: See also [Why are pure functions faster in Mathematica code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333450/why-are-pure-functions-faster-in-mathematica-code)

Answer (score 1):

They are inevitable to apply when you use such functions as `Map` or `MapThread` mapping binary functions on some expressions. Under binary here I mean functions taking two arguments. In this case, you want that only one position of the binary function is active.
  Let me give an elementary example. Let

```
eq = a*x == b;
```

be a simple equation and assume that we want to divide both parts by `a`. This can be done as follows:

```
    Map[Divide[#, a] &, eq]
(*  x == b/a   *)
```

This is the place, where the pure function is extremely useful.

Disclaimer: yes, I know, that in the latest MMa version there is a special function, `DivideSides`, to make such things. But this is only an example of operations of this sort. There are many others.

Comment: Suggestion for a better readability : to replace "binary function" by "two variables function". I think that a lot of people will think that binary means some kind of 0/1 or True/False function. (I'm not sure)

Comment: @andre314: Correct as to avoiding misleading the reader. But alas, a "unary" relation (or function) takes one argument, a "binary" relation (or function) takes two arguments, a "ternary" relation", etc....